# How to create android Emulator using command line

Tags: android, appium, qa-developer, calabash-android

I have done it using Android studio 
On android professional site commands are not clearly mentioned 
There is lot of confusion

Below is the following command:

android create avd -n  -t  --skin WVGA800

What to set as the targetID and  what should be in skin

Moreover how to create the  avd with specific API level ,
Suppose I want to create android 1.5 
How to do that?

I know that this is very basic questions but I didnt get any specified answers  elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on something similar myself recently, and had similar issues with outdated and unclear instructions. Here's what I got to work for me:

- To create a new device run `avdmanager create avd -n NewEmulator -k "system-images;android_25;google_apis;x86" -d pixel`
- -n is the name of the emulator
- -k is the system image / API version you want to use
- -d is the device to create

The above command will create a Pixel called New Emulator running Android 7.1.1 Nougat

The Android Developer [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html) helped some, and error messages in the Terminal are pretty verbose. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552218/android-create-avd-size-on-windows-command-prompt)

android create avd -n Ev o4G -t 9 -c 8000MB -s 480-800

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html